# Unexplainable behaviour regarding c++ constructors

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor

I want to create these classes: A *robot* class, a *HLC* (high level controller) class and multiple *LLC*s (low level controller). The HLC controller will switch between the LLCs. The robot has the state ( position, velocities etc) of the real robot. All the controllers (HLC,LLCs) have the robot as an attribute, as they need the robot state. So i want the same instance of the robot object to be in all the LLC and HLC objects.

After some time i got it working. However, during the "debugging", **i couldn't understand some behaviours**, and that is why i am asking this question:

The problematic code is presented below (with comments and text. I also mention what is required to get it working). I will ask the questions that arose after the code.

```
#include <iostream>

class Robot{
    public:
     Robot(){ //default constructor
        std::cout<< "a robot is created  \n";
        val = rand();
     }

    int val;
};
```

Defining the LLC1 class, the correct way is to have `Robot & r` in order for all the classes to have the same instance of robot . However, i will put the inital problematic code `Robot  r` as the question is about outputs i couldn't explain during the debugging process.

```
class LLC1{
    private: 
        Robot r;

    public:
        LLC1( Robot & Robj): r(Robj) {
            // r = Robj; //if not commented out, then 3 robots would be created
            std::cout<< r.val << " in LLCconstructor" <<std::endl;
        }

        int getVal(){ return r.val; }
        void add1(){ r.val ++; }
};


class HLC{
    private:
    Robot r;
    LLC1  lc1;

    public:
    
    //General member functions:
    void printVal(){
        std::cout<< r.val <<std::endl;
        std::cout<< lc1.getVal() <<std::endl;
    }

    void control(){ lc1.add1(); }

    //constructors will be presented in detail 
};

int main() {

    HLC hl; 

    hl.printVal();
    hl.control();
    hl.printVal();

    return 0;
}
```

I though of creating two constructors.

**The first constructor**:

```
    HLC(): lc1(this->r) {
        std::cout<< r.val << " in HLCconstructor" << std::endl;
    };
```

With this constructor the programm was being executed, however, the output wasn't the desirable:

```
a robot is created  
1804289383 in LLCconstructor
1804289383 in HLCconstructor
1804289383
1804289383
1804289383
1804289384
```

**Question 1:**

It seems **only one instance of robot is created**. And the same instance is in both the HLC and LLC1. However, when i add one using the *add1* function of LLC1, the value doesn't change for the robot of HLC. So, they must be different. **How is this possible?**

**The second constructor**:

```
     HLC() {
         r = Robot();
        lc1 = LLC1(r); 
     };
```

Compiling with this constructor fails. My theory is that first lc1 is created using a default constructor (and as there is no default constructor for LLC1, it fails), and then we try to assing a value to it, using a copy constructor.

**Question 2:** In a class constructor, if an attribute isn't initialized before the brackets ("{}"), then a default constructor is called to create an instance, and then a copy constructor is used if we assign a specific value to it?

This is supported from the following facts:

1. Because the second constructor fails to compile.
2. Because if the constructor of LLC1 is modified like that:

```
LLC1( Robot & Robj) {
            r = Robj; //if not commented out, then 3 robots would be created
            std::cout<< r.val << " in LLCconstructor" <<std::endl;
        }
```

Then there are two "a robot is created" messages in the output.

Comment: [Not reproducible here](https://godbolt.org/z/dvd86jcYv). Two robots are created in [this demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dvd86jcYv)

Comment: you are right. I fixed it

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. You say, "the correct way is to have `Robot & r`" but then, in your code (class) you have `Robot r;` as a member.

Comment: I want to reproduce the problems i had but i couldn't explain. The question is before i want to be able to understand what caused these problems. i clarified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems only one instance of robot is created

No, it's not. Two instances are created. The second instance gets copy-constructed, and you're not logging it.

```
Robot(){ //default constructor
```

That's just the default constructor, now, add a `Robot(const Robot &)`, here, log it, and watch your 2nd robot make its grandiose entrance.

```
LLC1( Robot & Robj): r(Robj)
```

This is going to copy-construct `r`. You did not define a copy constructor so a default one gets created.

Comment: I tried it and indeed there are two instances. As for the second part of the question, am i right?

Comment: Not quite, this conflates copy construction with assignment. They are independent of each other. A default constructor default-constructs all class members, that do not have a default value. A default copy constructor will copy-constructs all class members. Assignment is not involved, at any point.